# ¿Cómo puedo usar la base de datos de IONOS con laravel en desarrollo?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-8

He comprado un hosting compartido.

He estado buscando por todo como realizar una conexión de manera remota con phpmyadmin de ionos/1and1 a una conexión con Laravel. He modificado el .env, sin embargo sigue sin funcionar y me da el siguiente error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dbs5681716 and table_name =
 migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos_2021_2022-harmony\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos_2021_2022-harmony\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. ")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos_2021_2022-harmony\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=db5006881118.hosting-data.io;port=3306;dbname=dbs5681716", "dbu2708094", "Contraseña", [])
```

Me gustaría realizar la conexión para realizar el desarrollo y utilizar esa base de datos, ya que es un trabajo que debo hacer con más compañeros.
El proyecto laravel lo he subido con fileZilla a ionos. Pero obviamente sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: En el panel de control del servidor debes habilitar conexiones remotas para MySQL (MariaDB o el motor de base de datos que estés usando) y después reiniciar el servicio del motor de base de datos. Probablemente también se tenga que abrir el puerto en el Firewall para permitir conexiones externas.

Comment: He revisado el panel de control del servidor y aunque te da los datos para conectar de manera remota, no te permite reiniciar el servicio. El problema con laravel es que no reconoce de donde proviene la base de datos. He hecho una prueba desde local y con el local sí que funciona...

Comment: ¡Bienvenid@ a SO en español! Léete [ask] y realiza el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. En tu pregunta veo esto: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.` que me da la sensación que estas usando un nombre de host que tus servidores de nombres no saben reconocer.  Prueba usando una IP directamente (la del servidor de hosting) para que no tengan ese problema y a ver si ese error cambia al menos.